Is MIT Kerberos V5 in any way dependent on rpcbind on Linux?
I was wondering if MIT Kerberos is dependent on rpcbind in any way on Linux. If yes, when and why?
I haven't come across any resource online that addresses anything related to this. I do know that MIT Kerberos uses GSSAPI and RPCSEC_GSS which a security layer on top of RPC mechanism. But that's about it.

So no, MIT Kerberos V5 itself is not dependent on rpcbind on Linux. However, I think your confusion might arise from certain use cases where Kerberos is used with services that do involve RPC.
Kerberos operates independently of RPC mechanisms, the Key Distribution Centre and related Kerberos utilities communicate over standard network protocols (UDP/TCP) using well-known ports like 88 but this does not involve rpcbind.
If you’re setting up Kerberos for general purposes like securing SSH or HTTP, rpcbind is not needed. However if you’re securing RPC-based services like NFSv4, you’ll likely need rpcbind because of the underlying RPC needs not because of Kerberos itself.

Ah i see. Thanks a lot!. I was going through the source code and came across some functions such as svc_register() which takes in a bool parameter for protocol to be used (tcp, udp) for the service to be registered with the portmap service. I assumed that this would make use of rpcbind. Could you shed some light on this?. Is it only used in NFS or NIS services?

There is a slight relationship, in that the MIT Kerberos kadmin protocol is indeed a Sun RPC service that uses RPCSEC_GSS – although it uses a fixed TCP port and doesn't touch the portmapper (rpcbind) at all. The "main" KDC protocol doesn't use Sun RPC, of course. (although I faintly remember DCE Kerberos using a customized KDC protocol that spoke DCE-RPC...)
